# Why does this switch statement (case_else too) not work if I try to forward pipe it?

Tags: r, switch-statement, magrittr

Why does this work:

```
 est <- unlist(column) %>%
    sample(i, replace = TRUE) %>%
    matrix(nrow = B, ncol = i) # %>%
  
  est <- switch(param,
           "mean" = rowMeans2(est, na.rm = TRUE),
           "sd" = rowSds(est, na.rm = TRUE),
           stop("Invalid `param` value. Valid values are 'mean' or 'sd.'")
           ) # %>%
  
  est <- mean(est)
```

But this does not:

```
  est <- unlist(column) %>%
    sample(i, replace = TRUE) %>%
    matrix(nrow = B, ncol = i) %>%
    switch(
      param,
      "mean" = rowMeans2(., na.rm = TRUE),
      "sd" = rowSds(., na.rm = TRUE),
      stop("Invalid `param` value. Valid values are 'mean' or 'sd.'")
    ) %>%
    mean()
```

The example using pipes gives the following error:

> Error in switch(., param, mean = rowMeans2(., na.rm = TRUE), sd =
> rowSds(.,  :    EXPR must be a length 1 vector

Also found `case_when` fails using pipes:

```
  case_when(
      param == "mean" ~ rowMeans2(na.rm = TRUE),
      param == "sd" ~ rowSds(na.rm = TRUE),
      TRUE ~ (stop("Invalid `param` value. Valid values are 'mean' or 'sd.'"))
    ) %>%
    mean()
```

With a different error:

> Error in `case_when()`: ! Case 1 (`.`) must be a two-sided formula,
> not a double matrix.

### Minimal code sample for repro:

```
# Sample data
set.seed(123)
column <- data.frame(X1 = rnorm(100))

# Parameters
i <- 5
B <- 100
param <- "mean"

# Load matrixStats
library(matrixStats)

# My function
myFunc <- function(i, column, B, param) {
  est <- unlist(column) %>%
    sample(i, replace = TRUE) %>%
    matrix(nrow = B, ncol = i) %>%
    switch(
      param,
      "mean" = rowMeans2(., na.rm = TRUE),
      "sd" = rowSds(., na.rm = TRUE),
      stop("Invalid `param` value. Valid values are 'mean' or 'sd.'")
    ) %>%
    mean()
  
  # Print the result
  print(est)
}

# Call the function for testing
myFunc(i, column, B, param)
```

Comment: That's due to an oddity of the `%>%` pipe.  If you pass the preceding value as `.`, in some cases it is still **also** passed as the first argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `switch` inside the pipeline, so the previous output will take the place of its first argument `EXPR`. That's not a scalar, so that's an error, and it's also no longer the `param` which you intended to use. You can easily get around this by parsing `param` first, and you also only need to do this once (not for every value in the pipeline):

```r
myFunc <- function(i, column, B, param) {
  ## Parse once, outside pipeline
  paramfunc <- switch(
    param,
    "mean" = \(x) rowMeans2(x, na.rm = TRUE),
    "sd" = \(x) rowSds(x, na.rm = TRUE),
    stop("Invalid `param` value. Valid values are 'mean' or 'sd.'")
  )
  
  ## Insert above into pipeline
  est <- unlist(column) %>%
    sample(i, replace = TRUE) %>%
    matrix(nrow = B, ncol = i) %>%
    paramfunc() %>%
    mean()
  
  # Print the result
  print(est)
}

myFunc(i, column, B, param)
#> 0.5044144
```

Comment: Very cool.  Didn't know you could do that.  So it's essentially evaluating the `param` and "setting" the function before entering the pipeline. Then inside the pipeline, it calls the previously "set" function. Wow.  Thanks!

Comment: If I'm calling this function within an `mapply` call, I'm guessing the `paramFunc` needs to be defined *inside* the `mapply` - correct?  So it can be parsed for each individual call from `mapply` ?

Comment: @CBRF23 to your second point, no -- regular scoping rules apply. You could define the function in the global environment and the `mapply` scope will look for it there if it can't find anything more local. It might not be great practice if that depends on arguments you're providing to the wrapping function though.